# Internationalize custom model errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, error-handling

How can I handle translation of my custom errors validation? Can I pass a symbol and then do something in my yaml files?
Here is my code:

```
 def validate
    errors.add(:kind, "something i want to translate") unless KINDS.include?(kind)
  end
```

Greg

Answer (score 0):

I found out.

```
errors.add(:kind, I18n.t(:key, :scope => [:activerecord, :model]) unless KINDS.include?(kind)
```